# Should I make a new Store or use an existing store? - Mobx State Tree?

Tags: mobx, mobx-state-tree

I have classic example of Companies and Employees.

Right now I have a CompanyStore that has Array of companies and each company can have an array of employees.

Now this structure works great when in my admin section and you want to see how many employees are in your company and stuff like that.
Now I am not too sure about, what to do for a employee who is trying to login in my site.

Do I do the login ajax call in the CompanyStore? The employee Model? or do I make a new EmployeeStore?

Comment: Can you post some code?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should do login in neither way.

There should be some login information like tokens, access controls, last login time, etc., that are nothing to do with companies and employees. So, you'd better create a `LoginUserStore` for those information.

After that, you can do the login call in the `LoginUserStore`. But that may not be the best practice.

I think it's better to create a util class to do all api calls, and then you can do some common data processing there, such as error handling, header settings, etc. If the call succeeded, pass the result back to `LoginUserStore`.

Besides that, I doubt whether it is OK for an employee to see the information of all other employees. If it is not OK, maybe you should reconsider your `CompanyStore` to keep your data safe.